# Android dialog title and divider color not changing

Tags: android

I have created custom `Dialog`.
I wants To change my `Dialog` title color and Divider line color.
I have gone through many answers but still M not successful.

I have tried different methods like:

```
int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Red);
```

And used the following code:

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog_caseadd);
    dialog.setTitle("Add new court");
    final Resources res = getResources();
    final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
    inal View titleDivider = dialog.findViewById(titleDividerId);
    titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.alerttitle);
    final EditText casetype= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text); 
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    Button dialogButtoncancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtoncancel);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(casetype.getText().toString().equals(""))
                Alert.showError("Error", "Please enter case type", CaseType.this);
            else
                 if(Network.isOnline(getApplicationContext()))
                     new WebTask().execute();
                 else
                     Alert.showNetworkError(CaseType.this,inflater);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    dialogButtoncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
```

That above code is not working, divider line and title color shows in blue color only.
Please help me change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog_caseadd);
    //this method help me for title color change
    dialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Add new case stage</font>"));
    //this method help me for divider color change
    int dividerId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```